# Weird crash when accessing the ACAccountStore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I've just re-factored my code which posts to social networks using Social Framework(previous code worked fine with the same fmw!). And now I'm getting the errors like:

`[ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I've logged the account store object and it exists - `store is: <ACAccountStore: 0x8c2cec0>`

The code where it crashes:

```
NSLog(@"[SocialSharingManager sharedInstance].accountStore is:
 %@", [SocialSharingManager sharedInstance].accountStore);   
ACAccountType * facebookAccountType = [[SocialSharingManager sharedInstance].accountStore
 accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSDictionary * options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : kFacebookAppId, ACFacebookPermissionsKey : permissions, ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceEveryone};
[[SocialSharingManager sharedInstance].accountStore
 requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

            if (granted) {...}
```

The second type of error:

[image]

These errors appear when I try to get access either to FB or Twitter account. Any suggestions? P.S - all things are going on main thread - you can see it on the screen-shot

EDIT: Don't know why the picture is so small, so please use zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was not funny = ) I've accidentally changed the scheme to iPhone Simulator 5.0 so the reason of crash is evident - the Social Framework appeared with iOS 6.0. I was perplexed because the project compiled with no warnings.

Comment: Thank's for your attention ))